# How to make 3d array's second array to be different

Tags: java, arrays

Can somebody help me?
I want to have an array like this. [[[10, 75]], [[10, 75],[20, 80]], [[10, 75], [15, 80], [20, 90]]]
And this is my code:

```
public class StackSize {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int n = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        int[][][] array = new int[n][][];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            String[] line = reader.readLine().split(" ");
            int m = Integer.parseInt(line[0]);
            int k = Integer.parseInt(line[1]);
            array = new int[n][m][2];
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                String[] line2 = reader.readLine().split(" ");
                int cm = Integer.parseInt(line2[0]);
                int pm = Integer.parseInt(line2[1]);
                array[i][j][0] = cm;
                array[i][j][1] = pm;                  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My code is saving only the last inputs. Like, if I enter  [[[10, 75]], [[10, 75],[20, 80]], [[10, 75], [15, 80], [20, 90]]] my array will look like [[[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0]], [[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0]], [[10, 75], [15, 80], [20, 90]]]. I want the second array to be different every time.

Comment: I can't help but think there is an easier solution to your problem then a `3D array`

Answer (score 0):

```
array = new int[n][m][2];
```

reassigns `array`, creating a new 3d array filled with zeros - so if you've previously put values into it, they are lost.

Instead, just assign a new 2d array to `array[i]`:

```
array[i] = new int[m][2];
```